# cannot run rviz for TurtleBot

Tags: rviz, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

I received the following

```
rviz revision number 1.6.7
ogre_tools revision number 1.6.3 
compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
Loading general config from [/home/turtle/.rviz/config]
Loading display config from [/home/turtle/.rviz/display_config]
RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1 
Segmentation fault
```

Please help me if anyone knows what is wrong. Thank you very much.

Background: Clearpath TurtleBot with Kinect and iRobot Create; Ubuntu 10.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56923/cannot-run-rviz-for-turtlebot/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-03**:
Are you using a laptop with nvidia graphics card ? If so, try installing bumblebee and run optirun rosrun rviz rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I re-installed the nvidia driver and it works now.

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

then

sudo -i

sudo nvidia-xconfig

then restart the computer.

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1